# SSH Command in my FTP dev folder?

Tags: magento, ssh, ftp

Intro:
I have 2 folder on my ftp, one for my main website and one for the dev website.

Question:
If I run a ssh command into my magentoroot\dev\shell folder, should I worry about consequences on my main website?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Unless the two site use the same database

Answer (score 0):

Please, note in case you need to work on development website. You need a separate database and file system. If database in common there must be possibility of configuration change while working in admin or while performing operations and installation of new extension. So, always try different database for staging and production website